# Failed to register ServiceWorker due to unsupported MIME type ('text/x-js')

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Following [these instructions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#5) to  add that "Add to Homescreen" functionality, I had to register a ServiceWorker. Unfortunately I can't get this to work. Chrome logs two errors:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
>
> The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/x-js').

My code to register the ServiceWorker is:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(reg){
    console.log("ServiceWorker installed.");
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("ServiceWorker not installed: ", err)
  });
}
```

I don't know why Chrome supposes this was a `x-js` script. The code is at the bottom of my `index.php` file before the closing `</html>` tag.

Has anyone got an idea, why this won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add MIME type text/x-js to your server, which I assume is apache.

https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/configuring_mimetypes_on_the_server/

Comment: When I add `AddType text/x-js` to my .htaccess file, I get a Internal Server Error.

Comment: Did you try this?

<Files "*.js">
    ForceType text/javascript
</Files>

Comment: `ServiceWorker installed.` Thank you so much! :)

Comment: to summarize, whenever you want to add a MIME Type, you need to look for its shape, which is not always the same as the error.